# How to show marker in Open layer 3

Tags: jquery, openlayers-3

I am trying to show markers on map  in open layer 3. Below is the code which i used. Can someone help me to find issue as it doesn't display any icon on given position.

```
var app = angular.module('Openlayers', []);

//The list of points to be connected
var dataSource1 = [{
    "title": 'Duero',
    "lat": '40.480243',
    "lng": '-3.866172',
    "description": 'This is Duero'
}, {
    "title": 'Reyes Catolicos',
    "lat": '49.47806',
    "lng": '-1.870937',
    "description": 'This is Reyes Catolicos'
}, {
    "title": 'Guadarrama',
    "lat": '58.478998',
    "lng": '-2.878755',
    "description": 'This is Guadarrama'
}];

var defaultIconPath = 'images/location.jpg';
var centerPosition = dataSource1[1];
var vehicleIconpath = 'images/vehicle.ico';
```

I have used below call to call the method :

```
 $scope.populateMarkers($scope.dataPoints, defaultIconPath);



$scope.populateMarkers = function (data, iconPath) {
        var features = [];

        angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
            debugger;

            var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([value.lng, value.lat], 'EPSG:4326',
                'EPSG:3857'))
            });


            var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                    anchor: [0.5, 46],
                    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                    opacity: 0.75,
                    src: iconPath
                }))
            });

            iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
            features.push(iconFeature);
        });
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: features
        });

        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource
        });

        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    }
```

Comment: The code itself seems appropriate. First idea is `iconPath` is wrong. Do you even have it initialized? Try removing it to see if default marker is shown. And also try zooming out to the whole world. maybe coords are wrong.

Comment: Yes i have initilized iconpath. In debugging i can see that. But still i tried to remove that but it didn't show default icon as well. I have modified  question with more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openlayers doesn't like when data is in the wrong format. 
Your **coordinates have to be NUMERIC**, but now they are Strings.
Just do :

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
     geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(value.lng), parseFloat(value.lat)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
});
```

to parse them to float and you'll be fine.